# Can rust projects share build artifacts?

Tags: rust, static-libraries, rust-cargo

I have one Rust project that generates a static library, and several others making applications that depend on the library via a `Cargo.toml` entry:

```
[dependencies]
lib_project = { path = "/path/to/lib_project" }
```

Currently each application will build a separate copy of `lib_project` during its build. Is there a way for them to use the existing built library from `/path/to/lib_project/target` instead? Or more generally, is there a way for multiple Rust projects to share build artifacts for common dependencies?

Comment: Not really, rlibs aren't really static libraries in the traditional sense, they are more a dump of a mixture of machine code and internal compiler IR, which is very compiler version specific. Theres usually enough generic code in rust that caching the monomorphic subset doesn't seem that useful.

Comment: If the projects share the same workspace, I believe they will share the build artifacts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the exact use case for a [cargo workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html).

A cargo workspace allows you to have several libraries and/or binary crates share a single target directory.

A cargo workspace has a `cargo.toml` file at the top level, which identifies the libraries and/or binaries that are part of the workspace, and then subdirectories containing the `cargo.toml` and other files/dirs for each of the crates that make up the workspace.

Cargo creates a single target directory at the top level, which contains build artifacts for all the contained crates. This avoids the need for rebuilding the libraries if they are used multiple times.